# ngx-translate only loads translations in prod mode

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have an Angular 5 app with ngx-translate, I use something like this in my app module and component:

```
// app.component
// ...
constructor (private translateService: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en-us');
    translate.use('en-us');
}

// app.module
// ...
function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        // ...
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
  // ...
```

When I `ng serve` my app, my translations are not loaded at all, and no activities in network tab. When I `ng serve -e prod`, translations are loaded.

**Edit:** The differences between serving in prod or dev environment:

1. `json`s are not loaded. In `prod` I see requests to `i18n/de.json` request. In `dev`, no request.
2. Translation is, obviously, not done in dev.

There are no errors in browser console whatsoever.

What am I missing?

Angular 5.1, ng-cli 1.6, ngx-translate 9.0.1.

Comment: what is the error that appears on the browser's console?

Comment: No errors. The translations are not done, and I don't see requests for json files fired.

Comment: Do you have set the file: angular-cli.json?

Comment: Yep, everything is cool there. It wouldn't run on prod mode otherwise, I think.

Comment: In angular-cli.json, search this:
"apps": [
    {
      ...
      "assets": [
        "assets/",
        "i18n/"
      ]

Comment: I have that line. As I've said, the translation works and is loaded in prod mode and not in dev mode. Both use the same angular-cli.json

Comment: I can confirm this... translation i18n can be loaded on the view just on prod mode/server. Have been struggling with a similar issue couple of moths ago. It did work just on prod server - in my case on docker where I use it for production.

Comment: k.vincent maybe you can give your details here on this issue: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/755

Comment: Can you tell us what is the solution here? @Zlatko

Comment: Sorry, it was a while ago,i  don't remember any more.